# How to cleanly uninstall and reinstall Qt?

Tags: qt, installation

I've been trying to reinstall Qt 5.1.1 in /opt/Qt/ on my Linux Mint 16 machine. I've installed and reinstalled a few times and somewhere along the line Qt got mad at me and threw an error while installing component Essential Modules.

```
Error during installation process (qt.5.1.1.gcc_64.essentials): 
Could not open installer://qt.511.gcc_64.essentials/5.1.1icu_51_1_ubuntu_11_10_64.7z 
for reading: Unknown error.
```

I have tried [the maintenance tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257822/how-can-i-uninstall-qt5-that-i-installed-from-run) to completely uninstall Qt so I could start over again, but that didn't do the trick; same error.

Suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered removing Qt directory ?

Comment: I ended up running the Maintenance Tool, removing the directory, _restarting the machine_, and  then reinstalling and that did the trick.